# How to insert special characters into MySQL using Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have several csv files in am loading into MySQl using Java. In the Description field I have several Special Characters that are causing the load to fail. I am using LOAD DATA INFILE as seen in the code block below. This is nested in a for each loop which parses an array of filenames / tables and runs through each combination until it is finished with all the files.

Here is my jdbc connection string where I am passing a definitive collation param/value for UTF8 collation

```
 static String  url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/iber_stage?verifyServerCertificate=false&amp;characterEncoding=UTF8";
```

other connection parameters and parsing an array of filenames/tablenames

```
 final String sql1 = ("TRUNCATE TABLE" + tableName);
 final String sql2 = ("LOAD DATA INFILE" + filetoEat  + "INTO TABLE staging." +tableName + "CHARACTER SET UTF8 FIELDS TERMINATED BY',' ENCLOSED BY '\"\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES");

        try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        st = con.createStatement();
        st.executeUpdate(sql1);
        rs = st.executeQuery(sql2);

        if (rs.toString() != null) {
            returnMsg = rs.toString();
            System.out.println(returnMsg);        
            updFlag = 0; 
            String strRecs = returnMsg.substring(40);
            updateControlTable(updFlag, strRecs);
        }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(update.class.getName());
            lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
            updFlag = 1;            

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(update.class.getName());
            lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            updFlag = 1;

        }
```

The code is working fine until it comes across a special character like a degree symbol or micro symbol µ within a Material Description . At that point it throws an Exception

```
Invalid utf8 character string: 'LUG'
```

The string LUG is followed by a µ symbol. The DB is set to utf8 - `utf8_unicode_ci` and the column in question is a VARCHAR(60) that holds material descriptions.
I have tried using  `ESCAPED BY '\\'` but I can't seem to get it working correctly. I have also tried `CHARACTER SET UTF8`. I have also tried different collation ie, `utf8_general_ci` to no avail.

Any insight is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding

```
CHARACTER SET UTF8
```

to the `LOAD DATA INFILE` instruction?

Full doc: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

Comment: Yes, I tried it a couple days ago and it still throws the same Exception. I edited my post to reflect that I tried to set the charset. I pretty much tried everything i could based on the MySQL docs for LOAD DATA INFILE over the last couple days, but thanks for the effort

Answer (score 0):

Can you check with database collation `utf8_general_ci` and character set as `utf_8`, It may work for you.

As It applies Unicode normalization using language-specific rules.

Comment: This was the original UTF8 collation I was using when I first saw the exception. I just now tried it again and it still throws the same Exception. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured that I would answer this now that I found the solution. Because I am using Java to run the `LOAD DATA INFILE` via JDBC the JDBC driver seems to be checking the collation at the DB and not the actual table being loaded as it is parsing the file. So you can't have the DB set to UTF-8 and have a Latin collated table as you would be able to do with an `INSERT` statement. I had tried to set the Table collation as Latin and even had the field in question Latin, but until I changed the entire DB to Latin it was failing. The CSV files are large so checking every char in question is not easy, but I was catching the Exceptions in Java and was able to determine that the error was generated by the JDBC driver and was complaining that "Character at line xx is not a UTF-8 character" Running in Debug allowed me to see more details.

I then concluded it must not be looking at the Latin collated table it would be filling, but was looking at the DB which was still set to UTF-8. Changing the DB to Latin was all I needed to do.

I hope this will help others in the future.

Pat